# Change delegate user by trigger?

Tags: trigger, user-management, delegate

Please how can i get the delegate user changes by triggering some apex code ? 
I preferred to do it with a workflow but the pb is that workflow can't update field in a lookup relationship and we can only do a lookup relationship with the Object user.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using PB with flow to set this value.

Comment: No i didn't 
i'm just a newbie and i din't tried PB i thought it will be easier with a small trigger.
Could u advice me a good tutorial for Process Builder please ? 
thank you in advance

Comment: In learnt most things from Rakash's blog https://rakeshistom.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 0):

The field is is on the User object and called `DelegatedApproverId`

Comment: Thank you brovasi.
But could you please share a sample code how to ti build a trigger to change it as i can not change it by workflow ? 
Thank you in advance for you quick answer